# How to automatically search my entire site for any content embedded using oEmbed?

Tags: facebook, oembed

How can I carry out an automatic search of all pages/posts on my site for any content embedded using oEmbed (preferably Facebook/Instagram content)?

The reason I ask is because [this WPBeginner post](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-facebook-and-instagram-oembed-issue-in-wordpress/) says that on October 24th, all Facebook or Instagram content embedded on a site using oEmbed will be deprecated, and such content will be (slightly) broken. I'd like to first determine how much oEmbed content I have on my site.  My site is has a relatively large amount of pages/posts (content added by others), so manually searching each will be a bit tedious.

Would I perhaps need to carry out a database search?  Or a text search through all the files?

FYI my site uses Classic Editor throughought--not Gutenberg.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else wants to know the answer, I was able to find it elsewhere.  If you run this SQL query on your database:

`SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE (meta_value LIKE '%facebook%') OR (meta_value LIKE '%instagram%')`

the search results will contain, in-part, a list of all posts with FB/IG oEmbed content.  You may have to change the prefix `wp_` to whatever prefix matches your database (I had to).  And you also may have to specify your database name in the query.  I tested that query and it indeed works as advertised.  I'm also told that this SQL query might contain *only* a list of all posts with FB/IG oEmbed content (but I haven't tested it):

`SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE (meta_value LIKE '%fb-root%') OR (meta_value LIKE '%instagram-media%')`

One last thing is that the SQL query results indicated that my site had one post with FB oEmbed content.  But when I opened that post, it didn't contain any *rich* oEmbed content (i.e. content described in [this article](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-facebook-and-instagram-oembed-issue-in-wordpress/#comment-1084910), e.g. nice image, nice icon, nice text formatting, etc) All that exists on the page is a standard link to a Facebook page ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FO8D.jpg)).  Because of this, I took no action to fix the issue--based on the description of the issue, this particular content will be unaffected.

See [this post](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-determine-if-this-issue-affect-me/) on the WordPress forums for more info.